# How To Get Magento 2 Rest Api List

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I Want to a list off all magento 2 default rest api list.
it would be batter if i got all the custome rest api list as well.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Hello Dear, it is very interesting to get all list please find the below things:
>
> - Create a token :
>   project path $ `curl -X POST "http://magento240.local/rest/V1/integration/admin/token" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"admin@123"}'`

> Then you got the below token and use it in another command

*TOKEN - oqbdpoknkvnqluwqsv4xt2js1as38nyf*

*BASE URL - http://magento240.local*

> Get a JSON files
>
> Project path $
> curl -X POST http://magento240.local/rest/default/schema -H "Authorization: Bearer oqbdpoknkvnqluwqsv4xt2js1as38nyf" > magento2.api.schema.json

- After that, the "magento2.api.schema.json" is crated on your directory path so you can import it into the Postman.

  Note: This has your all custom API's list as well.
  If you want to open it in your browser you can use the swagger URL Ex:http://magento240.local/swagger

> You can also review the Magento docs from here: [magento rest api](https://r-martins.github.io/m1docs/guides/v2.4/rest/list.html)

Hope this helps you.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It is a very simple and quick way to get all the rest APIs of the customers.

Go to admin and click on System > Integrations

Step 1. Create add new integration
[image]

Step 2. Copy access token
[image]

Step 3. Open http://localhost/swagger and follow below screenshot
[image]